# JQuery validation of radio buttons and check boxes on same form

Tags: jquery, razor, checkbox, radio-button, jquery-validate

I have a form that creates a set of radio buttons and a set of checkboxes from the database. These are fixed at six radio and six checkboxes. They are for a questionnaire and a new version of the form opens when the user clicks the next button. In some cases, there will be four radio buttons and sometimes three. The same applies to the checkboxes, sometimes six or sometimes four.

I am really struggling to do JQuery validation on the form as it posts. I can get the radio buttons to works, but I cannot do the checkboxes successfully.

The Razor View is as follows:

```
 @if (Model.fldAnswerType == "Radio") { @Html.Label("", String.Format(Model.fldQuestion, 1))
<br /> if (Model.fldOption1 != null) {
<label class="containers">
    @Model.fldOption1
    <input type="radio" name="Radio" id="Radio" value="@Model.fldOption1">
    <span class="radios"></span>
</label>
} if (Model.fldOption2 != null) {
<label class="containers">
    @Model.fldOption2
    <input type="radio" name="Radio" id="Radio" value="@Model.fldOption2">
    <span class="radios"></span>
</label>
} if (Model.fldOption3 != null) {
<label class="containers">
    @Model.fldOption3
    <input type="radio" name="Radio" id="Radio" value="@Model.fldOption3">
    <span class="radios"></span>
</label>
} if (Model.fldOption4 != null) {
<label class="containers">
    @Model.fldOption4
    <input type="radio" name="Radio" id="Radio" value="@Model.fldOption4">
    <span class="radios"></span>
</label>
} if (Model.fldOption5 != null) {
<label class="containers">
    @Model.fldOption5
    <input type="radio" name="Radio" id="Radio" value="@Model.fldOption5">
    <span class="radios"></span>
</label>
} if (Model.fldOption6 != null) {
<label class="containers">
    @Model.fldOption6
    <input type="radio" name="Radio" id="Radio" value="@Model.fldOption6">
    <span class="radios"></span>
</label>
} }

<fieldset class="chkGroup">
    @if (Model.fldAnswerType == "Check") { @Html.Label("", String.Format(Model.fldQuestion, 1))
    <br /> if (Model.fldOption1 != null) {
    <label class="containers">
        @Model.fldOption1
        <input type="checkbox" value="@Model.fldOption1" name="chkGroup[]" id="Check1" class="Check">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    } if (Model.fldOption2 != null) {
    <label class="containers">
        @Model.fldOption2
        <input type="checkbox" value="@Model.fldOption2" name="chkGroup[]" id="Check2" class="Check">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    } if (Model.fldOption3 != null) {
    <label class="containers">
        @Model.fldOption3
        <input type="checkbox" value="@Model.fldOption3" name="chkGroup[]" id="Check3" class="Check">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    } if (Model.fldOption4 != null) {
    <label class="containers">
        @Model.fldOption4
        <input type="checkbox" value="@Model.fldOption4" name="chkGroup[]" id="Check4" class="Check">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    } if (Model.fldOption5 != null) {
    <div id="Checks"></div>
    <label class="containers">
        @Model.fldOption5
        <input type="checkbox" value="@Model.fldOption5" name="chkGroup[]" id="Check5" class="Check">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    } if (Model.fldOption6 != null) {
    <label class="containers">
        @Model.fldOption6
        <input type="checkbox" value="@Model.fldOption6" name="chkGroup[]" id="Check6" class="Check">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    } 
  }
</fieldset>
<p class="control-error" name="control-error" id="control-error">You must select an answer.</p>
<p class="checkerror" name="checkerror" id="checkerror">You must select an answer chk.</p>
<input type="submit " value="Next " id="btn " class="btn btn-sm btn-primary " />
```

My JQuery for the different elements is working at the same time and not individually depending on the type of element on the form.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myForm').submit(function () {
            if ($('#Radio').length) {
                console.log("Radio")
                if (!$("input[name='Radio']:checked").val()) {
                    $('#control-error').show();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $('#control-error').hide();
                }
            } else {
                $('#control-error').hide();
            }

            //If chk exists do the following
            if (!$("input[name='chkGroup[]']:checked").val()) {
                $('.chkGroup').each(function () {
                    console.log("Check")
                    if ($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) {
                        $('#checkerror').show();
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#checkerror').show();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#control-error').hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do here. MVC has built-in client and server side validation using `ValidationAttribute`'s applied to you model properties. NEVER generate the html for for controls manually. Use the string typed `HtmlHelper` methods. And none of that script has anything to do with validation.

Comment: You will notice that the question is about JQuery validation and not MVC validation.

Comment: Which is all done automatically by mvc! And there is nothing at all in your code relating to jquery validation (i.e. `jquery.validate.js`) anyway. Just show or hiding message is not validation!

Comment: I'm fully aware it is done automatically, the client has asked for all validation to be done client side with JQuery. The CDN's are in the head which is not included here. If you have an answer relating to this question please feel free to add your response.

Answer (score 0):

Your radio boxes all have the same Id - which may be causing the error since it doesn't know which one to validate.

Change the radio boxes to have a class, then should be able to use the same JS you used for the check boxes.

Edit:

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
        $('#body').hide();
            if ($('.Radio').length) {                  
                if (!$("input.Radio[name='Radio']:checked").val()) {
                    console.log("Radio")
                    $('#radioerror').show();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $('#radioerror').hide();
                }
            } else {
                $('#radioerror').hide();
            }               
        });

        $('#btnCheck').click(function () {
            if ($('.Check').length) { 
            if ($('input.Check[type=checkbox]:checked').length < 1) {  
              $('#chkerror').show();
              return false;
            }
            else {                            
                $('#chkerror').hide();
            }
           } else {
                $('#chkerror').hide();
            } 
        });
```

Comment: It works with the Radio buttons, but it is not working on the checkboxes, it just shows the error message then goes straight to the next question.

Comment: I've created this Fiddle so you can see waht I mean

Comment: I have updated the Fiddle to prevent the posting, but it won't detect that one of the checkboxes has been clicked.

Comment: I'm sorry, I twisted around what you were asking.  I'll look this over when i get a chance.